# Low frame rate with Irrlicht on Android

Tags: android, game-engine, android-ndk, irrlicht

I've compiled an Android port of Irrlicht from http://gitorious.org/irrlichtandroid/ and made an application to just load a lo res SkyBox. However, I get unpredictable frame rates. On emulator, fps never goes beyond 5. On my DELL XCD35 with eclair, it usually doesn't go beyond 10 fps, BUT, in about 1 out of 10 launches, the application runs nice at 60 fps.
Activity is configured for fullscreen landscape mode.

Following is the code, I've omitted class header files to keep the post short.

**BlueStoneActivity.java**

```
public class BlueStoneActivity extends Activity {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("irrlicht");
        System.loadLibrary("bluestone");
    }

    GLSurfaceView glView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        glView=new GLSurfaceView(this);
        glView.setRenderer(new IrrlichtRenderer(this));
        setContentView(glView);
        Debug.startMethodTracing("bstone");
        nativeOnCreate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        nativeOnDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
        Debug.stopMethodTracing();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    public native void nativeOnCreate();
    public native void nativeOnDestroy();
    public native void nativeOnPause();
    public native void nativeOnResume();
    public native void nativeOnResize(int w, int h);
    public native void nativeDrawIteration();
}
```

**IrrlichtRender.java**

```
 public class IrrlichtRenderer implements Renderer {
        BlueStoneActivity activity;

        IrrlichtRenderer(BlueStoneActivity activity){
            this.activity=activity;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 arg0) {
            activity.nativeDrawIteration();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
            activity.nativeOnResize(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 arg0, EGLConfig arg1) {
        }
    }
```

**JNI wrapper**

```
    #include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include "EngineManager.h"
#include "InputManager.h"

game::EngineManager *engine;

int importGLInit();
void importGLDeinit();

#ifndef _Included_com_devin_BlueStoneActivity
#define _Included_com_devin_BlueStoneActivity
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_devin_BlueStoneActivity_nativeOnCreate
  (JNIEnv *, jobject){
    engine=new game::EngineManager();
}


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_devin_BlueStoneActivity_nativeOnDestroy
  (JNIEnv *, jobject){
    engine->device->drop();
    importGLDeinit();
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_devin_BlueStoneActivity_nativeOnResize
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jint width, jint height){
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "NDK", "ONRESIZE - [%d %d]", width, height);
    engine->mWidth=width;
    engine->mHeight=height;
    importGLInit();
    engine->glInit();
}


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_devin_BlueStoneActivity_nativeDrawIteration
  (JNIEnv *, jobject){
    engine->drawIteration();
}


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_devin_BlueStoneActivity_nativeOnPause
  (JNIEnv *, jobject){
}


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_devin_BlueStoneActivity_nativeOnResume
  (JNIEnv *, jobject){

}


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**EngineManager.cpp**

```
#include <irrlicht.h>
#include "EngineManager.h"

namespace game {

EngineManager::EngineManager() {
    input=new game::InputManager();
    app=new game::ApplicationManager(input);
}

EngineManager::~EngineManager() {
}

void EngineManager::glInit(){
    device=createDevice( video::EDT_OGLES1, core::dimension2d<u32>(mWidth, mHeight), 16, false, false, false, 0);
    driver=device->getVideoDriver();
    scenegraph=device->getSceneManager();
    guienv=device->getGUIEnvironment();

    app->initApp(device);
}

void EngineManager::drawIteration(){
    device->run();
    driver->beginScene(true, true, app->clearColor);

    app->drawIteration();

    scenegraph->drawAll();
    guienv->drawAll();
    driver->endScene();
}

} /* namespace game */
```

**ApplicationManager.cpp**

```
#include "ApplicationManager.h"
#include "InputManager.h"

namespace game {

ApplicationManager::ApplicationManager(InputManager *in) {
    this->input=in;
}

ApplicationManager::~ApplicationManager() {
}

void ApplicationManager::initApp(IrrlichtDevice *device){
    this->device=device;
    this->driver=device->getVideoDriver();
    this->scenegraph=device->getSceneManager();
    this->guienv=device->getGUIEnvironment();

    // Camera setup
    camera=scenegraph->addCameraSceneNode();
    camera->setPosition(core::vector3df(20.0f, 15.0f, 15.0f));
    camera->setTarget(core::vector3df(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

    // Sample objects
    bool sceneLoaded=scenegraph->loadScene("/sdcard/BlueStone/redsky.irr");
    if(sceneLoaded)
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "NDK", "SceneLoaded");
    else
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "NDK", "SceneLoaded false");

    clearColor=video::SColor(255, 20, 40, 40);
    statsText=L"START";
    text=guienv->addStaticText(statsText.c_str(), core::recti(50,50,50+100,50+60), true, true, 0, 18, false);
    text->setOverrideColor(video::SColor(255, 64, 20, 20));
}

void ApplicationManager::drawIteration(){
    statsText=L"FPS: ";
    statsText+=driver->getFPS();
    text->setText(statsText.c_str());
}

} /* namespace game */
```

Please help !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it finally!!

It seems Android SDK has a bug. When you try to set screen orientation to landscape from AndroidManifest.xml using 'android:screenOrientation="landscape"', you get low frame rates on GLSurfaceView.
Using

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE );
```

in code solved all problems. My code now runs at consistent 60fps.

Comment: Do you know a good tutorial to setup Irrlicht and the Bullet physics engine on the android platform? Or could you tell me what I need to do to install it? Please contact me for this on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17572/how-do-you-setup-the-irrlicht-and-bullet-engines-for-android-development